# Declare a global website variable in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I have problems to include the THREEJS GLTFLoader.
The following Error occurs:
[image]

In my component I import first THREE and then the GLTFLoader script.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
window['THREE'] = THREE;
import 'three/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader';
```

As you can see in line 2, I try to set a global THREE variable, for the GLTFLoader script but when I type in the website's console `THREE` it's undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You should import `THREE` in your `GLFTLoader`.

Add `import * as THREE from 'three';` to the top of the file `three/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.ts`

**EDIT:** Sorry I miss understood what you are trying to do. 
I think you problem is a matter of load order. From your screenshot it looks like you are using webpack. It will load all import before running your code. So when `GLFTLoader` is imported the `window['THREE'] = THREE` hasn't been run yet.

Have a look in the complied file (or sources in Chrome) and you should see what code is actually running.

To solve you problem, copy the code from  `three/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js` in to your own file and add the `import * as THREE from 'three';` to the top of that file

Comment: GLTFLoader is not a typescript file. It's a .js from the node_modules folder.

Comment: Thank you, your answere works! But I get many warnings because of missing types. I found out that I can use the following code: `import * as _THREE from 'three';
const THREE: typeof _THREE = window['THREE'] = require('three');
require('three/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader');`